# Changing directory on mac affects all files in Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file-management

I simply wish to change the name of a folder that lies in my root project folder.

I have changed the name of a project (say from `Proj1` to `Proj2`).

I now have a folder on my desktop that reads `Proj2`. Inside is `Proj2.xcodeproj` and a folder called `Proj1` with all of my source files and resources.

I want to change that folder to be consistent and read `Proj1`, however if I change it every file in my xCode proj becomes red.

Is there a technique to change this folder within xCode such that I can rename the folder and keep all my files intact with the appropriate structure (such as what groups the files are in)?

Comment: even if it becomes red, you can close that project and reopen it again.

Comment: Do you want to rename the .xcodeproj file ? Or do you want to rename the folder name that contains the .xcode fiel ?

Comment: WHY DID THIS GET DOWNVOTED!

Comment: Xcode doesn't do that on its own. Unfortunately. Maybe try App Code for tasks like this, it's slightly more aware of the project <-> file system relationship and tries to keep it both up to date

Answer (score 3):

It's annoying, indeed.

However, there's no way to keep files on the hard drive (SSD, ..) and group names and the project structure in Xcode in sync automatically.

You can re-assign the locations of the files in your red folders manually to fix it.

Wish Xcode would offer a feature like this since we've switched to Xcode from MW CodeWarrior, but..

Answer (score 1):

After you rename the folder, open the project in Xcode and select this folder. You can choose the renamed folder in the File Inspector Pane.